# Optimize parallelism in migrating MySQL to MongoDB using python

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb

I am migrating a MySQL database to a mongodb and I'm discovering parallelism.
I have two main parts to my main program - first part turns a chunk of sql rows to documents and a second part to write them to mongodb.
I then run it on a pool of 4 processes.
The question: Currently all the processes run together, all query the MySQL and then all write to mongodb.
I feel that if I could split them it would be better - while one process is querying mySQL, another process can write to mongo and then switch.

- Could this be done?
- Would it be faster?
- What would be the best practice in order to do so?

for more details here is half-pseudeo code for simplicty:

```
def row_to_doc(row):
  #This takes a row and turns it into a document according to my schema

def mongo_write(args):
  row_min=args[0]
  row_max=args[1]-1
  chunk=500000
  myList=[]

  while myRow<row_max:
    #MySQL Part
    #query my sql from myRow to myRow+chunk
    for row in sql_cur.fetchall():
      doc=row_to_doc(row)
      myList.append(doc)
    #Mongodb part  
    collection.insert_many(myList,ordered=False)
    myRow+=chunk
    myList=[]
```

And the main part calls those function

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
  #records to process on a single machine    
  single_machine =   10000000    
  cpus           =          4
  start          = 3960000001
  args           = []
  #Create intervals for every process to work on different one.
  for i in xrange(cpus):
      args.append([single_machine*i+start, single_machine*(i+1)+start])
  #Create a pool of processes and start them
  pool = mp.Pool(processes = cpus)    
  pool.map(mongo_write,args)
```